# Alarm manager not work correctly, notification won't show up

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have two classes to build notification and for some reason none of them are showing any notifications although there's no error found.

I have:

1. Set the receiver on `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. use setsmallicon on builder
3. running it on MainActivity

This is the first class `NotificationHelper` which creates the channel and does most of the boilerplate code for notification:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

public static String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";
public static CharSequence CHANNEL_NAME = "dicoding channel";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
NotificationChannel channel;

public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannels();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void createChannels() {

    channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
    if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return notificationManager;
}

public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification() {
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Film Tv")
            .setContentText("Hey, cek katalog movie kamu sekarang!")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);

}
}
```

and the receiver class `AlertReceiver` which extends BroadcastReceiver to build the notification:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
    notificationHelper.getNotificationManager().notify(1, nb.build());


 }
}
```

and this is the main activity which contains `BottomNavigation` so I called it `BottomNavigation` where you should put the notification in. But strangely, only the bottom navigation loads and not the notification.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Calendar;

. . . . . .. . . . . . ..

public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity {


BottomNavigationView navView;
Toolbar toolbar;
private String title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bottom_navigation);
    navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // placing toolbar in place of action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    startAlarm();
    bottomNavigation();

    . . . . . . . . . . .  . . . . . . .

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void startAlarm() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

the bottom navigation showed up, and everything loads, only the notification won't show up. The phone is Nokia 6.1 with Android 28. Why won't the notification show?

Answer (score 1):

In `onReceive()`, try replacing `getNotificationManager()` with `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)`.

If that works, you can modify `getNotificationManager()` and go back to using it.

If it doesn't work, replace `startAlarm()` with the code inside `onReceive()` to help find out if the problem is with the alarm or the notification.

Comment: it gives me a red text when tryign to replace `getNotificationManager()` with `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)`

Comment: replaced `startAlarm` with the code inside `onReceive` and the notification didn't show up

Comment: is it the `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat` maybe?

Comment: how to build the channel with `NotificationManager.compat` ?

Comment: tried replacing `getNotificationManager` to return `NotificationManager.compat` and did the notify and build still not show

Comment: fixed error this line `
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }`